# TRichEdit adds blanks lines when change wordwrap (any recreate property)

Tags: delphi, word-wrap, trichedit

The following was found in Embarcardero RAD Studio 10.2.  I have not looked at other versions.

If you have a `TRichEdit` on your form that contains existing text (more than 1021 characters), and change the `WordWrap` (or any other recreate window) property, then the component will sometimes insert additional blank lines in the middle of your existing text.  It appears to depend on where the CR/LF characters land.

To demonstrate the problem, paste the following text into the `Lines` property of a `TRichEdit` on a form in Delphi:

```
01xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx78
02xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
03xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
04xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
05xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
06xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
07xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
08xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
09xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
10xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
11x456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
12xxxxxxx1xxxxxxxxx2xxxxxxxxx3xxxxxxxxx4xxxxxxxxx5xxxxxxxxx6xxxxxxxxx7xxxxxxxx
13x4567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901
x
```

The purpose of the sample text above is to have 1024 characters (counting the CR/LF at the end of the preceding lines) when you get to the last line (the 'x' on its own).  What comes after does not matter.

Now, with the above text in your `TRichEdit`, and still in design mode, toggle the `WordWrap` property a few times.  (The same thing should happen if you set up your form to do it at runtime.)  If your Delphi does the same as mine, the last line (the 'x' on its own) will start to separate from the earlier lines as new lines are inserted.

If you change the length of the 13th line - add or remove just one character - the problem seems to go away.

I say "seems to go away" because the 1022/1023 position for CR/LF is not the only sensitive positions.  I found more further on (when playing with larger text), but not always on the 1k borders (I think, not studied in detail).

I found the problem with `WordWrap`, but it happens with any of the properties that recreate the window handle (I think) - certainly `BorderStyle` does the same thing.

Has anyone else seen this?  Is it too much to ask if someone could try the above test in Delphi 10.3 to see if it's fixed?

Probably the only reliable fix (if 10.3 doesn't fix it) is to avoid using `TRichEdit`, or - and this is my next step for testing the problem - to create and use a derivation that inserts code to save and restore content during handle recreation.  Any other ideas?

**UPDATE** At runtime the problem only happens if the `PlainText` property is true.  At designtime it happens whether that property is true or not.

Comment: Wordwrap is designed to work with text that does not contain embedded CR/LF pairs (except at the end of paragraphs). You're inserting multiple CR/LF pairs (one at the end of each line). If you stop doing that, and simply use a space at the end of each line instead (except for between paragraphs), it will work properly. You can observe the same behavior in Notepad using the text you've included as your sample text here. Copy/paste it into Notepad, size the window so that it's too narrow to display a full line, and then toggle wordwrap on and off. IOW, it's not an issue with wordwrap or Delphi.

Comment: Ken, the problem was originally observed in some text with normal paragraphing etc, the example above was just trying to make it easy for people to see what is going on and reproduce it.  The point is that changing the display property of the control should not ever change the data content.  Changing wordwrap, borderstyle or scrollbars, none of them should alter the content - but if you to try what I've shown above you will find that Delphi is inserting newlines at the 1024 position.  (TMemo does not have this problem.)

Comment: I was able to reproduce. File->New->VCL Forms app. Drop a RichEdit, open the Lines editor, and paste in the sample text. Close and reopen the Lines editor, all is good. Still at design-time, change the BorderStyle from bsSingle to bsNone, and reopen the Lines editor. There is an extra CR/LF between the last two lines (leaving a blank line before the `x`). Close the Lines editor, change the BorderStyle again, and there's a second blank line between the last two.

Comment: Ken, I really appreciate you going to the effort to reproduce the problem.  It's always good to know I'm not seeing things, and that it's not something wrong with just my installation.  Thank you.